# Allure Report : Is it possible to generate a generic index.html that can be viewed from any machine?

Tags: allure

I have executed the tests and generated an index.html allure report which is specific to a particular IP and opened in my local machine. When i have tried to open the same HTML report in another machine it displays a blank report. So I have to generate a generic
index.html that can be viewed from any machine. Is it possible to create a generic index.html?

Answer (score 1):

In that case you should upload and store Allure results in cloud, so it will be widely accessible across PCs.
Or use CI/CD tools for test running, these tools also provide storing artifacts (i.e. Jenkins, Bamboo, CircleCI, TeamCity etc)